# How to Use RCurl or RMongo via HTTP with Authentication and Self Signed SSL to Read in JSON Data

Tags: json, r, mongodb, rcurl, rmongo

I am using R to write a program and perform some analyses. The data is being captured by an outside vendor with MongoDB in JSON format. They are providing it to me via a URI on port 443, which they want me to query using cURL. They have authentication in place and self signed SSL.

I can authenticate and dump the data via curl in Windows, however to create a long term sustainable solution it needs to all be done within R.

The vendor says that RCurl "should" work but they aren't providing any support and they basically just don't like the idea of using RMongo and have no comment on it (but if we could make it work that would be awesome, in my opinion).

I have the following packages loaded
- ggplot2
- DBI
- rjson
- RJSONIO (I sometimes don't load this one if I'm using rjson, or visa versa)
- RMongo
- rstudio
- RCurl

The self signed certificate caused issues even with curl, but those were resolved by editing settings in Ruby and then launching a cmd shell with Ruby and using curl that way. I'm not sure if the problems in R are related.

When trying to go the RCurl route I end up with commands/errors like this:

```
  x <- getURL("https://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:443/db/_authenticate", userpwd="xxxx:xxxxx") }{Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host
```

and when trying to use RMongo I'm even more clueless...

```
> mongo <- mongoDbConnect("xxx.xx.xxx.xxx")
```

> username = "xxxx"
>   password="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
>   authenticated <- dbAuthenticate(mongo, username, password)
>   Feb 25, 2013 4:00:09 PM com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector fetchMaxBsonObjectSize
>   WARNING: Exception determining maxBSON size using0
>   java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [/127.0.0.1:27017] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at com.mongodb.DBPort.*open(DBPort.java:224)
>       at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:101)
>       at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:82)
>       at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:142)
>       at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:151)
>       at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.fetchMaxBsonObjectSize(DBTCPConnector.java:429)
>       at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.checkMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:416)
>       at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:193)
>       at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.*_find(DBApiLayer.java:303)
>       at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:159)
>       at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:144)
>       at com.mongodb.DB._doauth(DB.java:503)
>       at com.mongodb.DB.authenticate(DB.java:440)
>       at rmongo.RMongo.dbAuthenticate(RMongo.scala:24)

```
Error in .jcall(rmongo.object@javaMongo, "Z", "dbAuthenticate", username,  : 
com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something
Feb 25, 2013 4:00:10 PM com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError
WARNING: emptying DBPortPool to 127.0.0.1:27017 b/c of error
java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [/127.0.0.1:27017]     bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:224)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:101)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:82)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:72)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:202)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:303)
at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:159)
at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:144)
at com.mongodb.DB._doauth(DB.java:503)
at com.mongodb.DB.authenticate(DB.java:440)
at rmongo.RMongo.dbAuthenticate(RMongo.scala:24)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your title is misleading at best. You are not using http:, but rather https:

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue in the past with RCurl where I needed to explicitly point it toward the security certificates to get it to work okay. I ended up needing something like this:

```
out <- postForm("https://url.org/api/",
                 token="IMATOKEN",
                 .opts=curlOptions(cainfo="C:/path/aaa.crt"))
```

I had manually exported the certificate I needed to get that working.

Also, it kind of looks like you should be doing a POST request given that URI, not a GET. Try the `postForm()` command, maybe?

EDITED TO ADD:

Okay, I think things might be a little more clear if we stepped back a second. Is your goal to get some file from a specific URL (basically, doing a wget but from within R)? Or is your goal to submit a form that subsequently returns the data you need?

IF you are just trying to get something that is behind basic (and also fairly INSECURE) HTTP authentication, you should do two things:

- Tell your data provider to use a more secure option
- Use the getURL() option as shown (using the www.omegahat.org example you posted about):

Code:

```
getURL("http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/testPassword/",.opts=list(userpwd="bob:welcome"))
OR
getURL("http://bob:welcome@www.omegahat.org/RCurl/testPassword/")
```

Now, if you need to submit a form to get the data, you would generally pass authentication tokens, etc, as parameters (so, in the example above, `token='.

Comment: Thank you TARehman, I am going to try out your solutions now. As a relative noob it may take me a little time, but I will post back this morning!

Comment: Where do the user/pass and port numbers go?

Comment: Hmmm, ok so I tried running this example of your command that I found online and it also returns an error for me. Does that mean I may have a corporate firewall issue? I can download packages just fine within RStudio, so I thought that the firewall was non-issue...
`#postForm("http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/testPassword/form_validation.cgi", 
            your_name = "Duncan", 
            your_age = "35-55", 
            your_sex = "m", 
            submit = "submit", 
            .opts = list(userpwd = "bob:welcome")) 
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host`

Comment: I tried your command and I got an authorization error, not a failure to connect to host.

Comment: Okay, the issue here (well there may be a few) that I can see is that I'm not sure the nature of the API that you are using to get your data. I'll edit my answer to reflect what I'm wondering.

Comment: Thank you for the update. OK, so it is httpS (sorry for any typo related to that on my part) and it's a MongoDB RESTful api (they call it their HTTP API on the website, but it's httpS in this case). He didn't give me a cert or token that I know of (maybe it was somehow automatically downloaded?). My goal is just to get some JSON data that's there. So what I want to do is the equivalent of curl -k --data "user/pass info" "https://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/db/test/_athenticate", followed by curl -k "https://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/db/test/_find"

Comment: I tried the getURL examples with the example credentials and also my own real info, but no joy. Still "Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host"

Comment: Since you tried it and got a different error I'm going to contact some more people about the possible firewall aspect

Comment: Update: I'm 99% sure you answered the question and I just need to fix this issue. It's going to be about 24 hours until my IT guru can look at the proxy issue. I'm new to StockOverflow except as a leecher, but I am going to try to give you credit for your helpful answer if it lets me (I may need more rep first or something, idk how it works exactly). Thanks again!

Comment: @Jason No problem, let me know how it works out, and you can always "Accept" an answer no matter your rep (since you asked the question). Anyway, I hope it works!